# How to capture multiple regex groups separated by logical AND inside an if statement in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

Here is the code -

```
my $s_ver = 'port=":443"; d=3600; v="10,20"';
my $b_ver = 'FB10';

if ($s_ver =~ /(v="[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*")/ && $b_ver =~ /FB(\d\d)/){
{
   print("$1 and $2\n");
}
```

Current Output -
`10 and`

Expected output -
`v="10,20" and 10`

How can this be achieved? Thanks.

Comment: Use two separate statements.  Trying to merge these captures into a single clause is just adding unnecessary headaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```perl
if ( 
   ( my ($s_cap) = $s_ver =~ /(v="[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*")/ ) &&
   ( my ($b_cap) = $b_ver =~ /FB(\d\d)/ )
) {
   print("$s_cap and $b_cap\n");
}
```

Comment: This way of doing it works in this specific use case but not in the general case.  If one of the valid regex matches is "0" or "", the `if` will fail.  One reason why the mega-one-liner isn't the right way to do this.

Comment: @lordadmira Re "*If one of the valid regex matches is "0" or "", the `if` will fail*", You are mistaken. [List assignment in scalar context returns the number of scalars return by its RHS](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129)

Answer (score 1):

You should usually never try to retain and use the $number variables over long code distances.  Long meaning 2 or 3 lines.  You should always capture them to normal variables immediately.  The reason is obvious from your attempt at subverting that wisdom.

Your attempt can't work because the $num match variables are localized and lexically scoped.  One sucessful match clobbers any previous one.  However a *failed* match does not reset them.  Caveat emptor.

There are machinations you can do to get your two regex tests into a single `if` but it's just not worth it.

Do this instead.

```perl
my $s_ver = 'port=":443"; d=3600; v="10,20"';
my $b_ver = 'FB10';

my $s_match = $s_ver =~ m/(v="[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*")/ ? $1 : undef;
my $b_match = $b_ver =~ m/FB(\d\d)/                 ? $1 : undef;

if ( defined $s_match and defined $b_match ) {
   print("$s_match and $b_match\n");
}
```

HTH

Comment: I wouldn't call `if( /.../ && /.../ )` any more of a machination than the the extra code you've employed to effectively do the same thing indirectly.

Comment: @brian d foy, But `if( /.../ && /.../ )` doesn't work. That's what the OP used and asked us to fix. Now, maybe you meant  `if( (my (...) = /.../) && (my (...) = /.../) )`, but I'm not sure that occurred to lordadmira.

Comment: Doing it correctly as a one liner is what I'ld call a machination.  You end up obscuring the boolean test in calculations and leaving uncovered edge cases. I did it this way to keep each piece of logic readable.  This is of course a matter of opinion, but Perl's ability to endlessly chain statements does lead to readability problems.  For quick and dirty code, sure, blast it out.